# Task Scheduled powershell script won't launch app in script, but will in ISE or interactively

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

**Update:**  settings the scheduled task to "run whether user is logged on or not" was the issue.  when you do this it doesn't allow running a program that has a gui in an interactive manner ie it won't launch the GUI.  Changing the setting to "run only when user is logged on" fixed the problem.  In my case I have a user logged on but disconnected and this task needs to run to reset an application overnight to clear out issues.  So this solved the problem.

I am trying to run this script as a scheduled task in a Windows 2012/2016 environment where the user running this is an administrator and the scheduled task is set to run as an admin.  When I run the script in Powershell ISE or interactively the script kills the application and then relaunches it as expected but when I run the scheduled task it kills the application but does not launch it.
the transcript also looks nearly identical to when I run it in the ISE.
The action is "powershell -file *scriptpath.ps1*"

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here but I'm not sure what it is.

From the task scheduler.

```
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20230629124853
Username: 
RunAs User: 
Configuration Name: 
Machine:  (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0)
Host Application: powershell.exe reset-qbwebconnector.ps1
Process ID: 20496
PSVersion: 5.1.17763.2090
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.2090
BuildVersion: 10.0.17763.2090
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is ...0629124853.txt
Launching file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks\QBWebConnector\QBWebConnector.exe
PS>$global:?
True
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20230629124853
**********************
```

From the ISE

```
************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20230629130614
Username: 
RunAs User: 
Configuration Name: 
Machine: (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe
Process ID: 14748
PSVersion: 5.1.17763.2090
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.2090
BuildVersion: 10.0.17763.2090
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Launching file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks\QBWebConnector\QBWebConnector.exe
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20230629130615
**********************
```

The script

```
Start-Transcript -OutputDirectory d:\scripts

#Find the qbwebconnector process for any users names *-QB and kill it.  
$processwebconnector = "QBWebConnector.exe"
$processes = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '$processwebconnector'"
foreach ($process in $processes) {
    $owner = $process.GetOwner()
    $username = $owner.User

    if ($username -like "*-QB") {
        Stop-Process -Id $process.ProcessId -Force
    }
}

#find the QBwebconnector program in the likely installation path and run it.  
$targetFileweb = "QBWebConnector.exe"
$basePathweb = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit"

# Function to recursively search for the target file
function Find-FileRecursivelyweb($pathweb, $fileNameweb) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $pathweb -Recurse -Filter $fileNameweb -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
        $_.FullName
    }
}


# Search for the target file recursively
$foundFilesweb = Get-ChildItem -Path $basePathWeb -Recurse -Filter $targetFileWeb -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

# Check if any files were found and run it
if ($foundFilesweb) {
    foreach ($fileweb in $foundFilesweb) {
        Write-Host "Launching file: $fileweb"
        Start-Process -FilePath $fileweb
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "File '$targetFileweb' not found in '$basePathweb'."
    }
```

Running it in the ISE, interactively.  tried action powershell.exe instead of powershell.

Comment: Thanks for providing information about the solution, but please note the best way to present a solution is in the form of an _answer post_ rather than by editing the information into your _question_ (it is perfectly acceptable to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). I've posted an answer in this case, so as to also provide some background information.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent was to **launch a *GUI* application from a scheduled task**:

- This **fundamentally only works if the task runs on the desktop (window station, session) of a *currently logged on user***.
- That is, the scheduled task must be configured with the **`Run only when user is logged on` option** selected in the **Task Scheduler GUI (`taskschd.msc`)**

  - Conversely, when `Run whether user is logged on or not` is selected, the task invariably runs *invisibly*, namely in the session in which all Windows *services* run (this *hidden* session is the one named `services` and has ID `0` in `qwinsta.exe`'s output).
- The **implications of selecting `Run only when user is logged on` are**:

  - The task **runs *visibly***, unless the process itself chooses to launch hidden (or launches in an unobtrusive way, such as by adding only a notification-are icon); if the process creates a (non-hidden, non-minimized) window on startup, which invariably happens with *console* applications, that window will pop up.
  - You must configure the task to **run as a real user** (as opposed to a *system* account) **or as a user *group***; in the latter case, the task will run if any member of that group happens to be logged on.
  - As the option name implies the **task will *not* run at the scheduled time if the specified user / no user from that group happens to be logged on** then.
  - If you choose the `Users` group, then the task will run if any user happens to be logged on, but if your task requires *elevation*, i.e. running as administrator, it will only work for those users that are also in the `Administrators` group, *provided that* you have also selected the `Run with highest privileges` checkbox.

---

Per your feedback, in your case the administrator in whose context the task runs *is* logged on (but disconnected) overnight, so reconfiguring your task with the `Run only when user is logged on` option solved your problem.